# What is the implicit equation $F(x,y,z) = 0$ for this non-standard torus?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

I was reviewing an old material on 3D surfaces from my college days. As an exercise, I am trying to write an implicit equation for a torus like manifold.

While it is relatively straight forward to describe this manifold in **explicit coordinate** form I was not able to write it in **implicit form** i.e. $F(x,y,z) = 0$. I am curious how to solve it, looking for help. Below are the details, and a short description of my attempt to pass from explicit coordinates to the implicit formula.

---

I am looking at a torus with a "major ellipse" and a "minor circle", this is a Torus like manifold obtained by revolving a "small" circle (a minor circle) about a "big" ellipse (major ellipse), see the drawing below.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

In a coordinate form this amounts to

$$\vec{r}(\alpha, \theta) = ( \widetilde{x},  \widetilde{y},0) + \frac{s \cos\theta}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\widetilde{x}}{a^2}\right)^2  + \left(\frac{2 \widetilde{y}}{b^2}\right)^2}}\left(\frac{2\widetilde{x}}{a^2}, \frac{2\widetilde{y}}{b^2},0\right) + (0,0, s \sin\theta) \tag{1}
 $$
With $\widetilde{x} = a \cos(\alpha), \widetilde{y} = b \sin(\alpha)$ (points on the major ellipse). Where $a, b, s$ are fixed (those determine the semi-major and semi-minor axis in the ellipse and the radius of the circle) and $\alpha, \theta$ run through $[0, 2\pi]$.

The expression above is obtained by drawing circles $n_0^2 + z_0^2 = s^2$ where $n_0$ and $z_0$ are in units of the normal to the ellipse $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{z}$ (unit vector in z-direction.) The normal to the ellipse at a point $\widetilde{x} , \widetilde{y}$  is

$$ \hat{n}(\widetilde{x}, \widetilde{y}) = 
\frac{\left(\frac{2\widetilde{x}}{a^2}, \frac{2\widetilde{y}}{b^2},0\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\widetilde{x}}{a^2}\right)^2  + \left(\frac{2 \widetilde{y}}{b^2}\right)^2}}
$$

Below is additional elaboration.

---

The coordinate form in equation (1) is a straightforward generalization of what is very well explained in [this math stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966503/implicit-equation-for-elliptical-torus). In that question Torus is built with major circle and minor ellipse, so that in coordinate form it is described by the following set of equations

$$ x = (c + u \cos(\beta)) \cos(\alpha) $$
$$ y = (c + u \cos(\beta)) \sin(\alpha) $$
$$ z = v \sin(\beta) $$

Where $\alpha , \beta \in [0, 2\pi]$. Setting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, the  implicit form of the above is given by

$$ \frac{(c - r)^2}{u^2} + \frac{z^2}{v^2} = 1 $$

Turning back to my problem, I was trying to play with (1), and see what implicit form it gives. So, for example, setting $\rho(\alpha) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{a^2} + \frac{\sin^2\alpha}{b^2}}}$ I obtained

$$
\sqrt{
x^2 \left[b + \rho(\alpha) \frac{u}{b} \cos\theta\right]^2
+
y^2 \left[a + \rho(\alpha) \frac{u}{a} \cos\theta \right]^2
} - ab = u\left(
\frac{b}{a} + \frac{a}{b}
\right)
\rho(\alpha)
\cos\theta +  \frac{\rho^2(\alpha) z^2}{ab} 
$$

I tried to massage this expression further to get rid of all places that $\theta$ and $\alpha$ appear, and be left with only the $x,y,z$, but so far this is without success, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Idea that can work, mostly a comment with formulas: take the implicit equation of the standard torus
$$(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - c)^2 + z^2 = R^2$$
and apply a linear transformation:
$$(\sqrt{p^2x^2 + q^2y^2} - c)^2 + z^2 = R^2.$$
Check if your parametric formula is solution for some $p,q$.

Comment: Thnk!Though there is something wrong. plug $\theta =0$ i.e $z = 0$. On the $xy$ plane I expect to see two ellipses a smaller one with axis of length $a - s$ and $b - s$. Your suggestion for $z=0$ reads $p^2 x^2 +q^2 y^2 = (R - c)^2$. So $(R - c)/ p = (a - s)$ and $(R - c) / q = (b - s)$. Writing $t = \cos^2(\alpha)$ and using the above I get $\left[ x\left( a + \frac{1}{\sqrt(x/a^2 +(1-x)/b^2)}\right)^2 / \left( (1 - a)a\right)^2 \right] +\left[(1-x)\left(b + \frac{1}{\sqrt(x/a^2 +(1-x)/b^2)}\right)^2 / \left( (1 - b)b\right)^2\right]  = 1 $. But plugging values $a,b,x$ the LHS$\neq1$.

Comment: @them, then my idea does not work...

Comment: My argument above in the comment was wrong, the slice at $z=0$ does not have a shape of an ellipse. So my argument above is incorrect still, the proposed equation cannot work since it does guarantee that for all $z^2$ the shape of the slice is an ellipse...